# What does Display Access button on Account Team do?

Tags: account-teams

Can any one please explain me the functionality of Display Access on Account Team.I am developing a similar functionality and I need to implement it on A VF page.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you wondering about why it's there or just how it works? Have you read the documentation and tried it out for yourself? Which parts do you need clarified?

Comment: I want to understand the functionality like when i click on the button what it is doing.

Comment: https://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/accountteam_def.htm

Comment: This link doesn't have the info on Display Access.

Answer (score 1):

Display Access displays the sales team's *minimum* access levels to the account and related opportunities and cases (the levels set in the AccountContactRole table). This button is only rendered on a "need to know" basis instead of just showing the access levels to anyone that stumbles across the list (e.g. anyone with access to the account).

This is a standard feature. You can mimic this behavior in visualforce through the use of reRender attributes, apex:commandButton buttons, apex:pageBlock areas, and so on.

```
<apex:pageBlock title="My Custom Related-List Lookalike">
   <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
      <apex:commandButton value="Do Something" action="{!doSomething}" reRender="outputArea"/>
   </apex:pageBlockButtons>
   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!output}" id="outputArea" var="item">
       <apex:column value="{!item.somevalue1}" headervalue="Header1" rendered="{!showcol1}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!item.somevalue2}" headervalue="Header2" rendered="{!showcol2}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!item.somevalue3}" headervalue="Header3" rendered="{!showcol3}"/>
   </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

This is just an example.

Comment: I want to implement the exact functionality as you mentioned above. AccountContactRole doesn't have the AccessLevel information.I am not able to find the table where the true access is stored.

Comment: In order to determine the true access level, you can query AccountShare to determine the user's access, or you can use the new UserShare object (if enabled). See http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_usershare.htm for that object.

Answer (score 1):

## ***CORRECTION***

The 'Display Access' button shows the MAX access a user has to the account record, whereas when they edit the account team member, the access that is displayed is the access level that the user has by virtue of being on the team.

In other words, assume when you click on the 'Display Access' button on the account, opportunity access for a user is “Read/Write” which is the maximum access they have as a result of their profile, their position in the role hierarchy, etc. However, when you edit the account team member record for the users, it shows the access level that was set up when they were added as account team members.

This discrepancy in access levels is what the message that displays when you click on the 'Display Access' button is meant to address: 
"Account team members may have greater access than defined by their account team membership." (i.e. the access level granted by virtue of being on the account team may be superseded by other factors).